# Tablet Pressure with Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, usb, tablet

Is there a simple way to get the pen pressure data from a usb tablet using python on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by reading input events on the input device node. I wrote some modules to do this. you can find it in the [Pycopia](https://github.com/kdart/pycopia3/blob/master/core/pycopia/OS/Linux/Input.py) project.

The disadvantage of this is that your program must run as root.

The [powerdroid](https://github.com/kdart/powerdroid) project also uses this, but that's old code now. You can see another example of synthesizing touch input in the [devices](https://github.com/kdart/powerdroid/blob/master/src/droid/devices.py) module. It probably won't work anymore, but you might start with that.

Comment: Is there a simple example of how I could access the pressure of a tablet using Pycopia?

Comment: @KevinGurney I updated the answer with pointers to a couple of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try using PySide, it's a QT Wrapper here: [QTabletEvent](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTabletEvent.html#PySide.QtGui.QTabletEvent).

Or you can use Python and PyGame: [Here.](http://www.akeric.com/blog/?page_id=798)

Comment: Are there any other alternatives which don't use QT or PyGame?

Comment: QTabletEvent is problematic for some Watcom tablets.